# sed — joining a range of selected lines

Tags: sed

I'm a beginner to `sed`. I know that it's possible to apply a command (or a set of commands) to a certain range of lines like so

```
sed '/[begin]/,/[end]/ [some command]'
```

where `[begin]` is a regular expression that designates the beginning line of the range and `[end]` is a regular expression that designates the ending line of the range (but is included in the range).

I'm trying to use this to specify a range of lines in a file and join them all into one line. Here's my best try, which didn't work:

```
sed '/[begin]/,/[end]/ {
N
s/\n//
}
'
```

I'm able to select the set of lines I want without any problem, but I just can't seem to merge them all into one line. If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way using `GNU sed`:

```
sed -n '/begin/,/end/ { H;g; s/^\n//; /end/s/\n/ /gp }' file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I never thought to use the hold space; I've learned a lot from your answer.

Comment: Note that this will discard *all other lines*. See below the answer by @Thor for a more robust solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is straight forward if you want to select some lines and join them. Use [Steve's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12558861/1331399) answer or my pipe-to-tr alternative:

```
sed -n '/begin/,/end/p' | tr -d '\n'
```

It becomes a bit trickier if you want to keep the other lines as well. Here is how I would do it (with GNU sed):

*join.sed*

```sed
/\[begin\]/ {
  :a
  /\[end\]/! { N; ba }
  s/\n/ /g
}
```

So the logic here is:

1. When `[begin]` line is encountered start collecting lines into pattern space with a loop.
2. When `[end]` is found stop collecting and join the lines.

Example:

```
seq 9 | sed -e '3s/^/[begin]\n/' -e '6s/$/\n[end]/' | sed -f join.sed
```

Output:

```
1
2
[begin] 3 4 5 6 [end]
7
8
9
```

Comment: why not sed -n '/begin/,/end/p' | gzip | gunzip | tr -d '\n' while at it?

Comment: @Valer: I am not sure I understand your point. However, I have added a second example which is able join selected lines while preserving the rest of the file.

Answer (score 1):

I like your question.  I also like Sed.  Regrettably, I do not know how to answer your question in Sed; so, like you, I am watching here for the answer.

Since no Sed answer has yet appeared here, here is how to do it in Perl:

```
perl -wne 'my $flag = 0; while (<>) { chomp; if (/[begin]/) {$flag = 1;} print if $flag; if (/[end]/) {print "\n" if $flag; $flag = 0;} } print "\n" if $flag;'
```

Comment: Thank you for the implementation in Perl. I've been meaning to learn it for a while, so I'll add it to my collection of code snippets to study.