# What is a script that would help parse a set of lines that have been incorrectly word wrapped?

Tags: perl, parsing, sed, awk

I have a set of call records that originally came from a (poorly formatted) PDF. The issue is that each record appears across multiple lines when placed in a text editor. The data seems to be "word wrapping" in the middle of fields. However, there is enough structure that I think a script could detect and fix incorrectly wrapped lines (by fix, I mean the script places all of a record's data on a single line instead of spewing it across multiple lines).

Example input:

```
8/21/201  
3  
08:4  
8  
817817935300 39 Inbound ARLINGTON 0:01 3001  
8/21/201  
3  
08:5  
2  
816036924529 26 Inbound WINTHROP 0:06 3001  
8/21/201  
3  
09:3  
1  
814697446313 48 Inbound SHINGLEHSE 0:01 7800
```

For these three records, the output **should** be:

```
8/21/2013 08:48 8178179353 39 Inbound ARLINGTON 0:01 3001  
8/21/2013 08:52 8160369245 26 Inbound WINTHROP 0:06 3001  
8/21/2013 09:31 8146974463 48 Inbound SHINGLEHSE 0:01 7800
```

I'm not partial to any particular approach. Seems like any of awk, sed, or Perl may be good starts, I'm just way too novice at scripting to figure this out in a timely fashion.

One pattern I was trying to exploit in Excel / VBA was that each record begins with a date stamp, so each record is contained in a "block" of lines starting from a date stamp and ending one line **before** the next date stamp. My code was not robust enough to handle it though, and future issues may arise that I think an awk / sed / Perl script may be better suited to handle.

Comment: Your question is very similar to [sed — joining a range of selected lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558578/sed-joining-a-range-of-selected-lines)

Comment: Thanks, that question does look similar and should be a useful resource as I try to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With awk (if the lines are all the times splited 5 times) :

```
awk 'NR%5{printf "%s", $0;next}1' file
```

Or another solution using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) based on the same algorithm :

```
perl -ne 'chomp; $.%5 && printf "%s", $_ or print "$_\n"' file
```

Edit : with the full output compliant as you expected :

```
perl -0777ne '
    my @arr = m!(\d+/\d+/\d+)\n(\d+)\n(\d+:\d+)\n(\d+)\n(\d+.*?\n)!g;
    my $i;
    for ($i=0; $i<$#arr; $i+=5) {
        print "$arr[$i]$arr[$i+1] $arr[$i+2]$arr[$i+3] $arr[$i+4]";
    }
' file
```

Comment: actually, adding trailing space doesn't give desired output

Comment: Space removed in my post. Need extra processing to full-fill the request.

Comment: Added full-filled answer

Comment: Interesting, thanks to you all for your help. I'll need to study this code in depth to really "get" how it works, but it does seem to be performing as expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Since you told us that `each record is contained in a "block" of lines starting from a date stamp and ending one line before the next date stamp`:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '
/^[[:digit:]]{1,2}\/[[:digit:]]{1,2}\/[[:digit:]]{1,4}/ {
    if (rec) print rec
    rec=""
}
{ rec = rec (rec?OFS:"") $0 }
END {if (rec) print rec }
' file
8/21/201        3       08:4    8       817817935300 39 Inbound ARLINGTON 0:01 3001  
8/21/201        3       08:5    2       816036924529 26 Inbound WINTHROP 0:06 3001  
8/21/201        3       09:3    1       814697446313 48 Inbound SHINGLEHSE 0:01 7800
```

Set `OFS` as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed -n 'N;s/\n//;N;s/\n/ /;N;s/\n//;N;s/\n/ /;p' input
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pe 'chomp; s|^(\d+/)|\n$1| if $. >1' file
```

Comment: @sputnick tnx, any suggestions to make it shorter?

Comment: Yes, see my post =)
But in awk

Comment: @sputnick looking at it